# Why is TensorExpand so slow for vector operations?

Tags: performance-tuning, vector, tensors, vector-calculus, system-performance

I would like to expand the following tensor expression:

```
$Assumptions = {(a1 | b | c | d | e | f | g | h) ∈ 
    Vectors[3, 
     Reals], (m | Ε1 | Ε2) ∈ 
    Reals};
exp=-32 I m^2 a1.(-b + d)\[Cross](-b + f) (b + c).(b + e) + 
 16 I m Ε2 a1.(b + e) (b + 
     c).(-b + d)\[Cross](-b + f) + 
 16 I Ε1 Ε2 a1.(b + e) (b + 
     c).(-b + d)\[Cross](-b + f) - 
 16 I m Ε2 (b + c).a1\[Cross](-b + f) (-b + d).(b + 
     e) - 16 I Ε1 Ε2 (b + 
     c).a1\[Cross](-b + f) (-b + d).(b + e) + 
 32 I m^2 a1.(b + c)\[Cross](b + e) (-b + d).(-b + f) + 
 32 I m Ε1 a1.(b + c)\[Cross](b + e) (-b + d).(-b + 
     f) - 32 I m Ε2 (b + c).a1\[Cross](b + e) (-b + 
     d).(-b + f) - 
 32 I Ε1 Ε2 (b + 
     c).a1\[Cross](b + e) (-b + d).(-b + f) + 
 16 I m Ε2 (b + c).(-b + f) (-b + 
     d).a1\[Cross](b + e) + 
 16 I Ε1 Ε2 (b + c).(-b + f) (-b + 
     d).a1\[Cross](b + e) + 
 16 I Ε1 Ε2 (b + c).(b + e) (-b + 
     d).a1\[Cross](-b + f) + 
 16 I m Ε2 a1.(b + c) (-b + 
     d).(b + e)\[Cross](-b + f) + 
 16 I Ε1 Ε2 a1.(b + c) (-b + 
     d).(b + e)\[Cross](-b + f) + 
 16 I m Ε2 (b + c).a1\[Cross](-b + d) (b + e).(-b + 
     f) + 16 I Ε1 Ε2 (b + 
     c).a1\[Cross](-b + d) (b + e).(-b + f) + 
 16 I m Ε2 (b + c).(-b + d) (b + 
     e).a1\[Cross](-b + f) + 
 16 I Ε1 Ε2 (b + c).(-b + d) (b + 
     e).a1\[Cross](-b + f) - 
 16 I a1.(g + h) (b + c).(b + e) (-g + h).(-b + d)\[Cross](-b + f) - 
 16 I a1.(-g + h)\[Cross](-b + f) (-b + d).(b + e) (g + h).(b + c) - 
 32 I a1.(-g + h)\[Cross](b + e) (-b + d).(-b + f) (g + h).(b + c) + 
 32 I a1.(-g + h) (-b + d).(b + e)\[Cross](-b + f) (g + h).(b + c) + 
 16 I a1.(-g + h)\[Cross](-b + d) (b + e).(-b + f) (g + h).(b + c) + 
 16 I a1.(-b + d)\[Cross](-b + f) (-g + h).(b + e) (g + h).(b + c) - 
 16 I a1.(b + e) (-g + h).(-b + d)\[Cross](-b + f) (g + h).(b + c) + 
 16 I a1.(-g + h)\[Cross](-b + f) (b + c).(b + e) (g + h).(-b + d) + 
 16 I a1.(-g + h)\[Cross](-b + f) (b + c).(-b + d) (g + h).(b + e) - 
 16 I a1.(-g + h)\[Cross](-b + d) (b + c).(-b + f) (g + h).(b + e) + 
 32 I a1.(-g + h) (b + c).(-b + d)\[Cross](-b + f) (g + h).(b + e) + 
 32 I a1.(-g + h)\[Cross](b + c) (-b + d).(-b + f) (g + h).(b + e) - 
 16 I a1.(-b + d)\[Cross](-b + f) (-g + h).(b + c) (g + h).(b + e) + 
 16 I a1.(b + c) (-g + h).(-b + d)\[Cross](-b + f) (g + h).(b + e) - 
 16 I a1.(-g + h)\[Cross](-b + d) (b + c).(b + e) (g + h).(-b + f) - 
 16 I a1.(-b + d)\[Cross](-b + f) (b + c).(b + 
     e) (Ε1 Ε2 - (g + h).(-g + h));

TensorExpand[exp]
```

However, it is really slow in my laptop. It takes over 12 hours. I think even if I do it manually, it could be faster.

Does anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also don't know the reason for the poor performance of `TensorExpand`, but as a possible workaround I may suggest using FeynCalc. The package has its roots in the field of the High Energy Physics, that is, it is not a toolbox for tensor algebra like xAct and company. Yet, the current development version already has a built-in support for 3-vectors, which was added there to accomodate for nonrelativistic field theories.

After having installed the development version according to the [wiki](https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/wiki/Installation#dev_automatic_installation) via

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/master/install.m"]
InstallFeynCalc[InstallFeynCalcDevelopmentVersion -> True]
```

we can do the following

```
vecs = {a1, b, c, d, e, f, g, h};

expTmp = (exp /. Dot -> dot /. Cross -> cross /. {
      dot[x_, cross[y_, z_]] /; SubsetQ[vecs, Variables[{x, y, z}]] :>
        CLC[][x, y, z], 
      dot[x_, y_] /; SubsetQ[vecs, Variables[{x, y}]] :> CSP[x, y]
      }) // ExpandScalarProduct[#, EpsEvaluate -> True] & // FCE
```

Here I converted your original expression into the FeynCalc notation using `CLC` (a shortcut for the Cartesian Levi-Civita tensor) and `CSP` (a shortcut for the Cartesian scalar product). Mathematically `CLC[][a,b,c]` corresponds to $\varepsilon^{ijk} a^i b^j c^k$, while CSP[a,b] stands for $a^i b^i$. The explicit Cartesian indices are suppressed for technical reasons, to avoid the expensive canonicalization. However, you can also define a standalone $\varepsilon^{ijk}$ via `CLC[i,j,k]` and 3-vector $a^i$ as `CV[a,i]`. `ExpandScalarProduct` is FeynCalc function for expanding scalar product, while FCE converts the result from the internal notation used by the package (`FeynCalcInternal`) to the more concise external notation (`FeynCalcExternal`).

Then we can convert the result back into your original notation via

```
res = expTmp /. {
     CSP[x_, y_] /; SubsetQ[vecs, Variables[{x, y}]] :> dot[x, y],
     CLC[][x_, y_, z_] /; SubsetQ[vecs, Variables[{x, y, z}]] :> 
      dot[x, cross[y, z]]
     } /. cross -> Cross /. dot -> Dot
```

which yields

```
(16*I)*m*\[CapitalEpsilon]2*(-a1 . Cross[b, e] - a1 . Cross[b, f] - a1 . Cross[e, f])*
  (-b . b - b . c + b . d + c . d) + (16*I)*\[CapitalEpsilon]1*\[CapitalEpsilon]2*
  (-a1 . Cross[b, e] - a1 . Cross[b, f] - a1 . Cross[e, f])*
  (-b . b - b . c + b . d + c . d) + (16*I)*\[CapitalEpsilon]1*\[CapitalEpsilon]2*
  (-a1 . Cross[b, d] + a1 . Cross[b, f] - a1 . Cross[d, f])*
  (b . b + b . c + b . e + c . e) - 
 (32*I)*m^2*(a1 . Cross[b, d] - a1 . Cross[b, f] + a1 . Cross[d, f])*
  (b . b + b . c + b . e + c . e) + 
 (16*I)*m*\[CapitalEpsilon]2*(a1 . Cross[b, d] + a1 . Cross[b, e] - a1 . Cross[d, e])*
  (-b . b - b . c + b . f + c . f) + (16*I)*\[CapitalEpsilon]1*\[CapitalEpsilon]2*
  (a1 . Cross[b, d] + a1 . Cross[b, e] - a1 . Cross[d, e])*
  (-b . b - b . c + b . f + c . f) + (16*I)*m*\[CapitalEpsilon]2*(a1 . b + a1 . e)*
  (-b . Cross[c, d] + b . Cross[c, f] + b . Cross[d, f] + c . Cross[d, f]) + 
 (16*I)*\[CapitalEpsilon]1*\[CapitalEpsilon]2*(a1 . b + a1 . e)*(-b . Cross[c, d] + b . Cross[c, f] + 
   b . Cross[d, f] + c . Cross[d, f]) - 
 (16*I)*m*\[CapitalEpsilon]2*(-a1 . Cross[b, c] - a1 . Cross[b, f] - a1 . Cross[c, f])*
  (-b . b + b . d - b . e + d . e) - (16*I)*\[CapitalEpsilon]1*\[CapitalEpsilon]2*
  (-a1 . Cross[b, c] - a1 . Cross[b, f] - a1 . Cross[c, f])*
  (-b . b + b . d - b . e + d . e) - 
 (16*I)*(-a1 . Cross[b, g] + a1 . Cross[b, h] + a1 . Cross[f, g] - 
   a1 . Cross[f, h])*(b . g + b . h + c . g + c . h)*
  (-b . b + b . d - b . e + d . e) - 
 (32*I)*m*\[CapitalEpsilon]2*(a1 . Cross[b, c] - a1 . Cross[b, e] - a1 . Cross[c, e])*
  (b . b - b . d - b . f + d . f) - (32*I)*\[CapitalEpsilon]1*\[CapitalEpsilon]2*
  (a1 . Cross[b, c] - a1 . Cross[b, e] - a1 . Cross[c, e])*
  (b . b - b . d - b . f + d . f) + 
 (32*I)*m^2*(-a1 . Cross[b, c] + a1 . Cross[b, e] + a1 . Cross[c, e])*
  (b . b - b . d - b . f + d . f) + 
 (32*I)*m*\[CapitalEpsilon]1*(-a1 . Cross[b, c] + a1 . Cross[b, e] + a1 . Cross[c, e])*
  (b . b - b . d - b . f + d . f) - 
 (32*I)*(a1 . Cross[b, g] - a1 . Cross[b, h] + a1 . Cross[e, g] - 
   a1 . Cross[e, h])*(b . g + b . h + c . g + c . h)*
  (b . b - b . d - b . f + d . f) + 
 (16*I)*(-a1 . Cross[b, g] + a1 . Cross[b, h] + a1 . Cross[f, g] - 
   a1 . Cross[f, h])*(b . b + b . c + b . e + c . e)*
  (-b . g - b . h + d . g + d . h) + (16*I)*m*\[CapitalEpsilon]2*(a1 . b + a1 . c)*
  (-b . Cross[d, e] - b . Cross[d, f] - b . Cross[e, f] + d . Cross[e, f]) + 
 (16*I)*\[CapitalEpsilon]1*\[CapitalEpsilon]2*(a1 . b + a1 . c)*(-b . Cross[d, e] - b . Cross[d, f] - 
   b . Cross[e, f] + d . Cross[e, f]) + (32*I)*(-a1 . g + a1 . h)*
  (b . g + b . h + c . g + c . h)*(-b . Cross[d, e] - b . Cross[d, f] - 
   b . Cross[e, f] + d . Cross[e, f]) - (16*I)*(a1 . g + a1 . h)*
  (b . b + b . c + b . e + c . e)*(-b . Cross[d, g] + b . Cross[d, h] + 
   b . Cross[f, g] - b . Cross[f, h] - d . Cross[f, g] + d . Cross[f, h]) - 
 (16*I)*(a1 . b + a1 . e)*(b . g + b . h + c . g + c . h)*
  (-b . Cross[d, g] + b . Cross[d, h] + b . Cross[f, g] - b . Cross[f, h] - 
   d . Cross[f, g] + d . Cross[f, h]) + 
 (16*I)*m*\[CapitalEpsilon]2*(-a1 . Cross[b, c] - a1 . Cross[b, d] - a1 . Cross[c, d])*
  (-b . b - b . e + b . f + e . f) + (16*I)*\[CapitalEpsilon]1*\[CapitalEpsilon]2*
  (-a1 . Cross[b, c] - a1 . Cross[b, d] - a1 . Cross[c, d])*
  (-b . b - b . e + b . f + e . f) + 
 (16*I)*(-a1 . Cross[b, g] + a1 . Cross[b, h] + a1 . Cross[d, g] - 
   a1 . Cross[d, h])*(b . g + b . h + c . g + c . h)*
  (-b . b - b . e + b . f + e . f) + 
 (16*I)*(a1 . Cross[b, d] - a1 . Cross[b, f] + a1 . Cross[d, f])*
  (b . g + b . h + c . g + c . h)*(-b . g + b . h - e . g + e . h) + 
 (16*I)*(-a1 . Cross[b, g] + a1 . Cross[b, h] + a1 . Cross[f, g] - 
   a1 . Cross[f, h])*(-b . b - b . c + b . d + c . d)*
  (b . g + b . h + e . g + e . h) - 
 (16*I)*(-a1 . Cross[b, g] + a1 . Cross[b, h] + a1 . Cross[d, g] - 
   a1 . Cross[d, h])*(-b . b - b . c + b . f + c . f)*
  (b . g + b . h + e . g + e . h) - 
 (16*I)*(a1 . Cross[b, d] - a1 . Cross[b, f] + a1 . Cross[d, f])*
  (-b . g + b . h - c . g + c . h)*(b . g + b . h + e . g + e . h) + 
 (32*I)*(-a1 . g + a1 . h)*(-b . Cross[c, d] + b . Cross[c, f] + 
   b . Cross[d, f] + c . Cross[d, f])*(b . g + b . h + e . g + e . h) + 
 (32*I)*(a1 . Cross[b, g] - a1 . Cross[b, h] + a1 . Cross[c, g] - 
   a1 . Cross[c, h])*(b . b - b . d - b . f + d . f)*
  (b . g + b . h + e . g + e . h) + (16*I)*(a1 . b + a1 . c)*
  (-b . Cross[d, g] + b . Cross[d, h] + b . Cross[f, g] - b . Cross[f, h] - 
   d . Cross[f, g] + d . Cross[f, h])*(b . g + b . h + e . g + e . h) - 
 (16*I)*(-a1 . Cross[b, g] + a1 . Cross[b, h] + a1 . Cross[d, g] - 
   a1 . Cross[d, h])*(b . b + b . c + b . e + c . e)*
  (-b . g - b . h + f . g + f . h) - 
 (16*I)*(a1 . Cross[b, d] - a1 . Cross[b, f] + a1 . Cross[d, f])*
  (b . b + b . c + b . e + c . e)*(\[CapitalEpsilon]1*\[CapitalEpsilon]2 + g . g - h . h)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer but may have a solution. I noticed that as I started to break the expression up into components and used TensorExpand, it was evaluating quite quickly. Have you considered trying that?

Comment: Yeah, it could be faster, but then, it fails at the reduce between the "components".