# keep variables in the correct position when TensorExpand

Tags: performance-tuning, tensors, vector-calculus, system-performance

I would like to expand a tensor expression of 3-d vectors. However, the code runs really slow, the problem is asked here:
[Why is TensorExpand so slow for vector operations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180764/why-is-tensorexpand-so-slow-for-vector-operations)

However, I found that by assuming the 3-d vectors as real numbers, the code could be faster. For example, to expand $(a-b)\times c.d$:

```
$Assumptions = (a | b | c | d) \[Element] Reals;
TensorExpand[( a - b)\[Cross]c.d]
```

Instead of using `$Assumptions = (a | b | c | d) \Vectors[3]`
I used `Reals`. It was really faster, except that the result was not perfect:

$$ a\times c.d+b (-1)\times c.d$$

I got a -1 here, which should be b.

Can we have some operations that could put the "b" in the correct place?